# Программа выдает ошибку (которая содержится в методе сортировки)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В общем этот метод должен сортировать элементы, которые стоят на непарных позициях 1 столбца([1][0] [3][0] и т.д.), 2-мерного массива, методом выбора, но вместо этого вылазит следующая ошибка :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147483648
    at PR1.sort(PR1.java:28)
    at PR1.main(PR1.java:47)
```

Сам код:

```
public class PR1 {
    private static int[][] getMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
        int[][] m = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                m[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 25);
        return m;
    }

    private static void display(int[][] mat) {
        for (int[] ints : mat) {
            for (int anInt : ints) {
                System.out.print(anInt + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void sort(int[][] mat) {
        for (int minI = 0; minI < mat.length - 1; minI++) {
            for (int minJ = 0; minJ < mat.length - 1; minI++) {
                int leastI = minI;
                int leastJ = minJ;
                for (int i = minI + 1; i < mat.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = minJ + 1; j < mat.length; j++) {
                        if (mat[i][j] < mat[leastI][leastJ]) {
                            leastI = i;
                            leastJ = j;
                        }
                    }
                    int tmp = mat[minI][minJ];
                    mat[minI][minJ] = mat[leastI][leastJ];
                    mat[leastI][leastJ] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }


            public static void main (String[]args)
            {
                int[][] m = getMatrix(7, 8);
                display(m);
                System.out.println();
                sort(m);
                display(m);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста весь код, что бы его можно было воспроизвести. И полный стек ошибки.

Comment: метод `sort()` вложенный цикл по `minJ`, а увеличивается `minI`

Comment: Олексій Моренець, спасибо что помогли решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static void sort(int[][] mat) {
    for (int minI = 0; minI < mat.length; minI++) {
        for (int minJ = 0; minJ < mat[0].length; minJ++) {
            int leastI = minI;
            int leastJ = minJ;
            int currentCol = minJ;
            for (int i = minI; i < mat.length; i++) {
                for (int j = currentCol; j < mat[0].length; j++) {
                    if (mat[i][j] < mat[leastI][leastJ]) {
                        leastI = i;
                        leastJ = j;
                    }
                    currentCol = 0;
                }

                int tmp = mat[minI][minJ];
                mat[minI][minJ] = mat[leastI][leastJ];
                mat[leastI][leastJ] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```